# SQL Server - how to PIVOT more than one column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Using this, //www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html, as my reference I have figured out how to pivot one dynamically-populated column into a series of columns.

However, I have 2 "dynamic" columns in the same Source Table which I need to PIVOT.  I have looked at some examples of how to do this using hard-coding but none (so far) with dynamic values.

Can anyone explain how to pivot more than one column?

I prepared this code to populate my `@PivotColumn` variable:

```
--- Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') +     QUOTENAME(META_KEY)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT META_KEY FROM [dbo].[TASK_META_DATA]) AS TASK_META_DATA
```

Then run this statement to associate the "flattened" column to a specific ID:

```
SET   @SQLQuery = 
'SELECT TYPE_ID, ' +   @PivotColumns + '
FROM [dbo].[TASK_META_DATA]
PIVOT (count(META_VALUE)
        FOR META_KEY IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'

--- Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

The second column I want to PIVOT is META_VALUE (Yes, the table has columns named META_KEY and META_VALUE).

I am baffled as to how to construct and use a 2nd PIVOT statement.

Comment: It would be really helpful, if you included the table structure, some sample data, and then the final desired result. Even better would be to create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with a working query.

Comment: I have not used sqlfiddle.com previously so hopefully this works.  I created my Table, inserted some sample data, and ran my existing PIVOT query here:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dea70/5.   What I am trying to do is Pivot both META_KEY and META_VALUE from Rows to Columns.